# Finding a non-piece wise function that gives us the $i$'th largest number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

A friend of mine was asked to find a non-piece wise function on four variables $i,a,b,c$ such that $f(i,a,b,c)$ is the $i$'th largest number among $\{a,b,c\}$. Using max and min or defining the function by pieces is prohibited.

The solution I found uses Lagrange Polynomials but to explain it I first had to find how to find the max, middle and min elements.

To find max I just use $$\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}+\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2}$$

This is because the max of $a,b,c$ is $max(max(a,b),c)$

To find min I just use the same approach: $$\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}-\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2}$$

To find the middle element I substract the maximum and minimum from $a+b+c$.

So it is $$a+b+c-(\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}+\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2})-(\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}-\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2})$$.

After having this I just build the lagrange polynomial so that

$$f(i,a,b,c)=\color\red{\frac{(2-i)(3-i)}{2}[\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}+\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2}}]+\color{blue}{\frac{(1-i)(3-i)}{-1}[a+b+c-(\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}+\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2})-(\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}-\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2})}]+\color\green{\frac{(1-i)(2-i)}{2}[\frac{c+(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})}{2}-\frac{|c-(\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|a-b|}{2})|}{2}}]$$

I would like this space to provide alternative constructions (If they could be simpler it would be better.

Thank you, regards.

Comment: Absolute value is allowed?  That's a piecewise function too.

Comment: Well, the question of whether something is piecewise or not is rather subjective. But my friend tells me absolute value is allowed.

Comment: The polynomial you constructed has four variables, but in your first sentence you want one in three variables. Which is it? Perhaps you want three separate functions: one for max, one for min, and one for middle. These would be in three variables.

Comment: Four variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's about the way I would do it,
although I would split it up
into a number of
subsidiary functions
(the "b" prefix
stands for "bear"):

$bmin2(a, b)
=\frac12(a+b-|a-b|)
$,
$bmax2(a, b)
=\frac12(a+b+|a-b|)
$,
$bmin3(a, b, c)
=bmin2(bmin2(a, b), c)
$,
$bmax3(a, b, c)
=bmax2(bmax2(a, b), c)
$,
$bmid(a, b, c)
=a+b+c-bmax3(a, b, c)-bmin3(a, b, c)
$.

Then I would write
your interpolating polynomial
in terms of
the min, max, and mid
functions.

To do this
for *four* variables
seems harder.
We can get the
min and max as above
(with another level of calls),
and we can get the
sum of the middle two,
but how to separate that sum
into the
individual values
so we can we can decide which is smaller
is not immediately clear to me.

I think I'll propose it as a problem.

Comment: Please give me link to the question if you do.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100663/how-to-sort-4-or-more-values-with-non-piecewise-functions